# Frequency to dB

Tags: amplifier, sound, decibel

As I understand for a sound wave the intensity is determined by the amplitude, frequency and properties of the space, but for amplifiers I have seen that the gain is expressed in dB and is a function of the frequency, so I would like to know how does it convert that frequency in dB, if it takes an specific amplitude of the wave.

Answer (score 3):

Frequencies are not normally expressed in dB, but they are expressed in a logarithmic measure all the time.

A musical staff is an expression of frequency in logarithmic measure.  One octave is a doubling of frequency.  So every four-and-a-half lines is twice frequency.

[image]

In electrical engineering, [the Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) plots frequency in logarithmic domain.  In the x axis, each line is ten times the frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Amplitude and frequency are separate concepts - in normal amplifiers, you don't convert gain, in dB, to frequency.

The amplitude of a sound wave determines the volume or intensity, while the frequency determines the pitch or tone (or musical note).

In an ideal amplifier, the gain should be identical for all frequencies.  Unfortunately, we can't make ideal amplifiers, so the gain of a real amplifier does vary with frequency.  For an audio amplifier, we might want the gain to be constant for all frequencies from 20 Hz to 20 KHz, but we can allow the gain to drop outside that frequenciy range.

Comment: the frequency does change the intensity, in the sears and zemansky's book appears I=0.5 sqr{rho B} omega^2 A^2 "a low frequency woofer has to vibrate with much larger amplitude than a high frequency tweeter to produce the same sound intensity", but I understand the dB notation in amp is just that, notation

Comment: It seems like you've got the cause and effect reversed... The frequency is treated differently by the circuit, and so the resulting output is at a different gain (dB).
You should read up on "filters" to see how circuits are designed to produce a desired gain at a specific frequency.

Comment: Perceptual intensity of a sound field is highly dependent on frequency, and weirdly also the overall spectral content of the test signal. (That latter property is part of what makes MP3 compression possible.) But don't confuse sound level with electrical gain.

Answer (score 1):

Generally amplifiers are designed so that they are FLAT across the frequency spectrum, between two values.

I'm having a little difficulty understanding your question, but I'm not sure you understand that complex signals can be broken down into their component frequencies. This property allows you to analyze systems that process complex signals as though they were working with simple, individual frequencies.

So for an amplifier, you can set an input signal at... say, 0dBV, then sweep the frequency from the lowest value of interested to the highest value of interest, and record the result. The gain (in dB) will vary (that is, the output might be -3dBV or +6dBV or somewhere in between) and you use that data to generate a gain plot vs frequency.

This might provide some background:
http://www.intmath.com/fourier-series/fourier-intro.php

Sorry if I've misunderstood your question.

Comment: I had seen fourier series, integrals and transforms in the DE book but not with the Harmonic Analysis, it might come in handy

Answer (score 0):

**dB** is a special kind of unit. It is meaningless without the context. Saying the room is at 70 dB (typical loud cocktail party) is only meaningful because context strongly implies that 70 dB SPL was meant. Saying the amplifier is at 10 dB (or turned up to 11, perhaps) is only meaningful because context strongly implies that meant 10 dB power gain.

This leads to a very common source of confusion when the context is missing, or not recognized. Which is what I think is happening to you here. Both [Sound Pressure Level (SPL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure) (an acoustic property) and [Gain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain) (in this case an electrical property) are commonly written in the logarithmic dB scale, but they aren't referenced to the same quantities.

(The pseudo-unit [bel (SI symbol B)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) is the base ten logarithm of the ratio between two power quantities. It is almost universally seen scaled by 1/10 to decibels, written as dB because whole powers of 10 are inconveniently large for most real world examples. The unit historically comes from work on the telephone system, and is named for Alexander Graham Bell.)

The SPL is defined by the power over a frequency spectrum that is limited to (and in some cases modeled after) the range of frequencies accessible to human hearing. The various weighting curves (typically A and C are the only ones in current usage) define how to filter the audio before computing SPL. Because of the wide range of power that is experienced as sound, SPL is expressed in dB by dividing it by the power in a standard reference sound. That reference sound was chosen to be well-defined in SI units, and to be near the threshold of human hearing. (A sinusoidal pressure wave with an amplitude of 20 µPa has 0 dB SPL by definition. All of the defined weighting curves cross 0 dB at 1 kHz to preserve this definition.)

System Gain is generally the ratio of power in to power out. While it is common to see gain expressed as a simple multiplicative scale factor, especially for systems with the special property of unity gain (no gain or loss at all), it is also commonly expressed in dB. This is especially true in audio, since hearing has a logarithmic response, you need your amplifier control to have logarithmic response too, so that turning the knob turns the volume up by perceptually similar amounts over the whole range.

So the amplifier specified in dB is simply specifying the power gain through the amp. Set to 0 dB and there is no gain. Set to 20 dB and it delivers twenty times the power out compared to the power in the input signal.

If the amplifier is set to 20 dB, and the ambient sound in the room (from a constant level signal, naturally) measures 64 dB SPL, then turning the amplifier up to 50 dB (adding 30 dB of additional gain) will (ideally) make the ambient sound measure 94 dB SPL. The arithmetic is that simple because dB is a logarithmic scale.

As a shameless plug and partial aside, I have a [series of blog posts](http://curiouser.cheshireeng.com/category/projects/pdm-microphone-toys/) about measuring SPL using some simple data processing and a digital MEMS microphone. A lot of the posts are about the gory details of recovering information from the digital microphone, but [this](http://curiouser.cheshireeng.com/2015/02/02/spl-is-logarithmic/) and [this](http://curiouser.cheshireeng.com/2015/03/20/diversion-what-is-sound-anyway/) are about sound itself and may be interesting.